# vscode webview dynamic update when event happen

Tags: webview, vscode-extensions

i am building vscode extention, create a webview with several buttons and text  area, i want the text area default in disable state, then enable if a button click.
maybe some further requirements is add one config item(maybe include several text areas) when click add button,

my question is, how can i  do ? use react framework?please give some suggestions.

i tried the searching example in github, I saw some example use react or vue,but i am not sure which is correct solution.

Comment: I'm afraid this question is way too broad. As a newcomer you should read and understand [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).